# Is there a asymtopic bound to a confluent hypergeometric function of ${_1F_1}(n,1.5n,nz)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, approximation, hypergeometric-function

As the title mentioned, is there a good way to approximate

$${_1F_1}(n,1.5n,nz)$$

where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $z$ is a real positive number. If the direct bound is difficult, an asymptopic bound (as $n$ tends to infinity) is also welcomed.

Comment: Some experiment suggests: as a function of $n$, this is decreasing and bounded below.  A start would be to determine the value of the limit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's quite helpful.

Comment: What about ${_1F_1}(n,1.5n,nz)$? Is there any promising approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [the integral representation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) of $_1F_1$ function to find the desiredt asymptotics:
$$_1F_1(a,b,z)=\frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(b-a)\Gamma(a)}\int_0^1e^{zt}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-a-1}dt$$
We will use the Laplace method to find the asymptotics at $n\to\infty$

First, we consider the case of $_1F_1(n,kn,z)$, where $z$ is fixed and $k>1$
$$_1F_1(n,kn,z)=\frac{\Gamma(kn)}{\Gamma(kn-n)\Gamma(n)}\int_0^1e^{zt}t^{n-1}(1-t)^{kn-n-1}dt$$
$$=\frac{\Gamma(kn)}{\Gamma(kn-n)\Gamma(n)}\int_0^1\frac{e^{zt}}{t(1-t)}e^{n\big(\ln t+(k-1)\ln(1-t)\big)}dt$$
We find the extremum (maximum) of $f(t)=\ln t+(k-1)\ln(1-t)$
$$f'(t)=\frac1t-\frac{k-1}{1-t}=0\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,t_0=\frac1k$$
$$f''\big(\frac1k\big)=-k^2-\frac{k^2}{k-1}=-\frac{k^3}{k-1}$$
Therefore,
$$_1F_1(n,kn,z)\sim\frac{\Gamma(kn)}{\Gamma(kn-n)\Gamma(n)}\frac{e^{zt_0}}{t_0(1-t_0)}e^{n\big(\ln t_0+(k-1)\ln(1-t_0)\big)}\bigg|_{t_0=\frac1k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-n\frac{k^3}{k-1}\frac{x^2}2}dx$$
$$=\frac{\Gamma(kn)\,e^{\frac zk}}{\Gamma(kn-n)\Gamma(n)}\frac{k^2}{k-1}\left(\frac{k-1}k\right)^{n(k-1)}\frac1{k^n}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}n}\sqrt{\frac{k-1}{k^3}}$$
$$=\frac{\Gamma(kn)\,e^{\frac zk}}{\Gamma\big(n(k-1)\big)\Gamma(n)}\frac{(k-1)^{n(k-1)}}{k^{nk}}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}n}\sqrt{\frac k{k-1}}$$

Using the Stirling formula I got a rather simple result:

$$\frac{\Gamma(kn)}{\Gamma\big(n(k-1)\big)\Gamma(n)}=\frac{\Gamma(kn+1)}{\Gamma\big(n(k-1)+1\big)\Gamma(n+1)}\frac{n^2(k-1)}{nk}$$
$$\sim\sqrt{\frac n{2\pi}}\frac{k^{kn}}{(k-1)^{n(k-1)}}\sqrt{\frac{k-1}k}$$
$$\boxed{\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,_1F_1(n,kn,z)\sim e^{\frac zk}\,\,}$$
what can be also checked numerically.

Now we can consider a more exotic case of $_1F_1(n,kn,nz)$:
$$_1F_1(n,kn,nz)=\frac{\Gamma(kn)}{\Gamma\big(n(k-1)\big)\Gamma(n)}\int_0^1\frac1{t(1-t)}e^{n\big(zt+\ln t+(k-1)\ln (1-t)\big)}dt$$
$$f(t)=zt+\ln t+(k-1)\ln(1-t)$$
At $k\in(1;2)$ and $z\in(0;\infty) \,\, f(t)$ has the maximum at
$$t_0=\frac{\sqrt{(\frac kz-1)^2+\frac4z}+1-\frac kz}2;\,\,t_0\in(0;1)$$
$$f''(t_0)=-\frac{kt^2_0-2t_0+1}{t^2_0(1-t_0)^2}$$
$$_1F_1(n,kn,nz)\sim\frac{\Gamma(kn)}{\Gamma\big(n(k-1)\big)\Gamma(n)}\frac{e^{nzt_0}t_0^n(1-t_0)^{n(k-1)}}{t_0(1-t_0)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-n\frac{kt^2_0-2t_0+1}{t^2_0(1-t_0)^2}\frac{x^2}2}dx$$
$$\sim\frac{k^{kn}}{(k-1)^{n(k-1)}}\sqrt{\frac{k-1}k}\frac{e^{nzt_0}\big(t_0(1-t_0)^{k-1}\big)^n}{\sqrt{kt^2_0-2t_0+1}}$$
This seems a bulky expression, but probably some simplifications are possible.

Comment: Minor comment: the last equality is just an asymptotic one.

Comment: @Gary Yes, you are right - thank you! Just correcting

Comment: Thank you very much, Laplace method seems very helpful when dealing with this problem. The final form meets my need perfectly, I will check the gap when $n$ is relatievly small, if it is acceptable, then it is the perfect answer for me. Thank you again!